# Correct equation for Ionic Conductivity (λ) in Solutions?

Tags: electrochemistry, erratum

We haven't started on Electrochemistry at school yet, but I did manage to find some time to read up on the topic. One thing I've noticed from when I started, is that different books and sites use different terms for the same symbols (For example: One book says Molar *conductivity* is represented by $\Lambda$, but another says it's Molar *Conductance*, and another book makes use of *both* Molar Conductance and Molar Conductivity, albeit inconsistently).

Now, my school textbook, as well as another book, *Physical Chemistry* by Wallwork and Grant employ the following equation for ionic conductivity:

$$\lambda=F\mu$$

Where $F$ is the Faraday constant and $\mu$ is the ionic mobility of the ion under consideration.

But I saw [another equation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_conductivity)

> $$\lambda=zF\mu$$
>
> Where $z$ is the ionic charge of the ion being considered.

So my question is, which of these equations are right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: $\lambda = z \mu F$ is correct. The [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140211093111/https://iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/publications/e-resources/ONLINE-IUPAC-GB3-2ndPrinting-Online-Sep2012.pdf)  provided by @Loong confirms this (page 73 of the document). To add to that I have provided you with a short derivation.

*Prerequisite reading (so to speak) for definitions of a few terms/notation would be my answers to this [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/59068/difference-between-molar-conductance-and-molar-conductivity/59077#59077), and this [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58090/what-happens-to-the-mobility-of-group-1-elements-going-down-the-periodic-table/58092#58092)*

Let me establish an important distinction (or definition) which can (possibly) be a source of confusion. The two relevant equations from my previous answer  to the first question are:

> $$\Lambda _{m}=\Lambda _{m}^{0}-K{\sqrt  {c}}$$

and,

> $$ \Lambda_{m}^{0}= \nu_{+}\lambda_{+}^{0}+\nu _{-}\lambda _{-}^{0}$$

Before I begin my discussion, I would like to note that "$\Lambda_m$" (uppercase ) is the molar conductivity of the solution, and "$\lambda$" is the molar conductivity of the ion (ionic conductivity). The second equation has a "special name", that I did not use in my previous answer-**"Kohlrausch's law of independent migration of ions"**.

In general for dilute solutions of strong electrolytes, molar conductivity can be decomposed into contributions from the different ions in solution (this is the spirit behind the previously quoted equation):

$$ \Lambda_m^0 = \Sigma \nu_i \lambda^0_i$$

Now, let's attempt to relate the ionic conductivity to the ionic mobility (it clearly makes sense to do so). So I am assuming we have a dilute solution of completely disassociated strong electrolyte with molar concentration $c$. Each formula unit of this electrolyte gives rise to $\nu_+$ cations of charge $z_+e$ and $\nu_-$ anions of charge $z_-e$.

The concentration of each type of ion is therefore, $\nu c$ ($\nu$ could either mean $\nu_+$, or $\nu_-$ to avoid unnecessary notational complexity).

the number density of each type of ions is:

$$\text{No. density} = \nu c N_\mathrm{A}$$

Now picture a small window of area $A$ in your solution. The number of ions that can pass through said window in a time interval $\Delta t$ is equal to the number of ions within the distance $s \Delta t$ (where $s$ is the drift speed of the ions)

$s \Delta t A$, happens to define a volume element and the number of ions in this interval is given by: $ V \times \text{no. density}$, i.e

$$ s \Delta t A \nu c N_\mathrm{A}$$

Thus, the flux of ions is

$$J_\mathrm{(ions)} = \frac{s \Delta t A \nu c N_\mathrm{A}}{ \Delta t A} = s\nu c N_\mathrm{A}$$

*remember flux always has dimensions of "something" per area per time*

Flux of charge is $$J_\mathrm{(charge)} = ze s\nu c N_A = z s \nu c F $$

*again, I am omitting the +/- signs for the sake of clarity. Also, note $F := e \times N_\mathrm{A}$*

Now, drift speed is $s = \mu E$, so the flux of charge (henceforth, simply J) is

$$J = z \mu \nu c F E$$

The current is charge flux times area, so

$$I = (z \mu \nu c F E)A$$

Additionally, $E = \frac{\Delta \phi}{l}$ (i.e the potential gradient)

$$I = (z \mu \nu c FA) \frac{\Delta \phi}{l} \tag{I}$$

Using Ohm's Law (i.e $\Delta \phi = IR$}, one obtains

$$I = \frac{\Delta \phi}{R} = G \Delta \phi = \frac{\kappa A \Delta \phi}{l} \tag{II}$$

Comparing the (I) and (II) one is lead to $$ \kappa = z \mu \nu cF$$

This is the ionic conductivity. We need to divide by concentration of ions to the get the molar quantity. The concentration of ions however is not $c$, but rather $\nu c$ and our final result is

$$\lambda = z \mu F$$

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I would suggest checking for the measurement units. Molar conductivity is measured in

$$C^2 s^{-1} m^{-2} N^{-1} \text{mol}^{-1}$$

so somewhere $F$ (and $z$) should be squared.

I think the possible inaccuracy with the previous answer is that the current (density) is the flux multiplied by the charge (per mole - i.e. $zF$).